# Debugging SQLJ files

Tags: java, debugging, ibm-rad, sqlj

I am working in IBM RAD IDE and I have a problem while debugging SQLJ files.

While debugging, when I come to methods that are in .sqlj files, debugger automatically opens .java files (which are harder to read) instead of .sqlj files.
I have enabled "debugging from SQLJ file" under "SQLJ Application" options, but it still does not work.

Is there a way to debug through .sqlj files instead of their, translator produced, .java files?

Thanks!